# How to document response json object in PAW

Tags: paw-app

I'm using PAW for testing and documentation writing, everything is okay, PAW works like its needed but when I send the request and got the JSON object response, how to document it (for example if I export to swagger, this is the responses/schema/properties/description part). I can write documentation/comment for request, variables, etc but not for response which is highly needed.

Thanks (PAW 3.1.10)

Comment: Hey Tibor! Unfortunately, it's not yet possible to document the response object in Paw (nor it is possible to document the request JSON body). At the moment, only request headers, query params and Form URL-Encoded body params can be documented. It's something we'll be working on.

Comment: @MichaMazaheri this is still a major shortcoming. This might be a deal breaker for me to continue using paw.